# Does the Mirror API support encoded polylines?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Can one use [encoded polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) to [render maps on timeline cards](https://developers.google.com/glass/location#rendering_maps_on_timeline_cards)?  If not, what is the practical limit on coordinate count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current implementation does not support encoded polylines yet. Please feel free to file a feature request on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) to request support for it.

Regarding the number of coordinates, there is currently no known upper limit but we will probably top it at a few hundred to limit resource consumption.